# asp.net core 2.0 Configuration.GetConnectionString doesn't seem to be reading appsetting.environment.json

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I can add a "ConnectionStrings" element to my appsettings.json file; however, when I copy and paste the same element in to my appsettings.Development.json file it doesn't seem to work. My `var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultDatabase");` line of code no longer works within `Startup.cs` and the `ConfigureServices()` method.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and when i go to the properties of the project and go to the Debug tab I can see that it is setting `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Development` so shouldn't the connection string within appsettings.Development.json work with the `Conifugration.GetConnectionString()` method?

Answer (score 3):

Ugh ok apparently I was pasting the code in to the `"Logging"` section element (right after the `LogLevel` element. Now that I truly have ConnectionStrings as its own element instead of a property of Logging all is well now.